# not stored value in Mage::registry after admin session expire

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, login, registry

I have added this code `Mage::register('test_checking_login', 1);` after admin login and when expire session or delete session directory from `var/` folder so `Mage::registry('test_checking_login')` displays null value why it does not display set value.How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 6):

I think you are confusing 2 concepts.
Session and Registry.

Session values are carried over from request to request until the session expires or until you remove them.

Registry values are some kind of global values but all in the same request.
As soon as the request is over your registry values are not available anymore.

I think you need

```
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setData('test_checking_login', 1)
```

Comment: Ok Let me try this code

Comment: Not work I am not getting Value 1  by this code Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getData('test_checking_login') after logout admin

Comment: If I set value in admin session variable after login and I want to get that admin session variable value after admin logout

Comment: I don't think that works when you logout, the session is destroyed.

Comment: therefore I was using mage registry so in this situation how can I achieve this functionality ?

Comment: I have no other ideas.

Comment: If you want data that lives longer than the session does you will need to either create a database table to hold this data or maybe write it to a file.

Comment: This almost sounds like you want a cookie @test. What are you trying to use this value for? Cookies aren't a great way to securely store information or values and there is probably a better way to design the feature depending on what it is.

Comment: @JonathanWommack I have created a different login page with custom module and create admin controller for other role user like sales manager so I do not want to permission to other role user to access admin login page so When Sales Manager login by custom admin login page it logged in correctly and its display limited resources but when session expires it redirects admin original login page.so I want to redirect to custom login page to other role user .So please advice me on this stuff.

Comment: @ShawnAbramson I think you are right .I need to track current logged in user track and store in database,can you please understand basic strategy ?

Comment: @test if it's two separate admin backends why not just change the default magento admin page in the settings. If it's not you should be managing permissions levels via ACL rules so this shouldn't matter beyond customizing the admin login page (which might as well be done universally).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully aware of your use case as your question is quite narrow but here's a shot.

From your comments on other answers you need this data to

- Persist after sessions are cleared (eg after logout)
- Persist Between separate requests
- And as you previously tried using the session, I assume this data is on a per-admin-user basis.

This really means it needs to be persistent storage (database) and linked to the current admin user.

There is a database field on the `admin_user` table called `extra` that I think you may be able to utilise. I don't *think* it's actually used anywhere in core magento, but you may want to watch out in case any of your extensions are using it.

Saving your data

```
$user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser();
if ($user instanceof Mage_Admin_Model_User && $user->getId()) {
    $extraData = $user->getExtra();
    if (!is_array($extraData)) {
        $extraData = array();
    }
    $extraData['test_checking_login'] = 1;
    $user->setExtra($extraData)->saveExtra($extraData);
}
```

Loading your data

```
$testCheckingLoginValue = 0;

$user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser();
if ($user instanceof Mage_Admin_Model_User && $user->getId()) {
    $extraData = $user->getExtra();
    if (is_array($extraData) && isset($extraData['test_checking_login']) {
        $testCheckingLoginValue = $extraData['test_checking_login']
    }
}

return $testCheckingLoginValue
```

Tech references

- Saving - https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php#L163
- Loading - https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/User.php#L469

Comment: Roadgers  I have created a different login page with custom module and create admin controller for other role user like sales manager so I do not want to permission to other role user to access admin login page so When Sales Manager login by custom admin login page it logged in correctly and its display limited resources but when session expires it redirects admin original login page.so I want to redirect to custom login page to other role user .So please advice me on this stuff.

Comment: If I set value after login in user table,if seller login in desktop and after few min it try to login by mobile so what happen ? because in this situation test login value entered 1 in table

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested the following but give it a go:

1. Using your custom login admin controller, set cookie when custom user role logs into system except admin role such as:
   `Mage::getModel(‘core/cookie’)->set($name, $value);`
2. Now, override `adminhtml_controller_action_predispatch_start` [I referred `Admin/Controller/Action.php` file to find out this event] method and set condition such as:

   ```
   if(Mage::getModel(‘core/cookie’)->get($name)):
      if(Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()):
        //Do process
      else:
        $this->_redirect('*/set/your/route');
      endif;
   endif;
   ```
3. Delete cookie when custom user role logs out from system.

In this way, say for e.g. if session gets expired but cookie has been set, it will be checked using that event specific method. In case if admin logs in then we do not need to set cookie [that can be achieved by checking user role when loginAction gets called].

As I mentioned, I have not tested this approach, may be anyone else can suggest better approach. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I tested but it does not work because whole cookie expire after logout even if I set custom value in cookie

Answer (score 0):

In Admin:

To save data

```
$value='my value';
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setData('name', $value);
```

To get it

```
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getData('name');
```

In Frontend:

To save data

```
$value='my value';
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setData('name', $value);
```

To get it

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getData('name');
```